# Small clarification needed on numpy.any for matrices

Tags: python, numpy

I am having a slight problem in getting numpy.any() to work fine on my problem.
Consider I have a 3D matrix of N X M X M matrix, where I need to get rid of any matrix MXM that has all its elements the same [all zeros to say].
Here is an example to illustrate my issue

```
x = np.arange(250).reshape(10,5,5)
x[0,:,:] = 0
```

What I need to do is get rid of the first 5X5 matrix since it contain all zeros.
So I tried with

```
np.any(x,axis=0)
```

and expected to have a results of

```
[FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE]
```

but what i get is

```
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Applying the follwing results with what I want but I hope that there is a better way without any loops

```
for i in range(x.shape[0]):
       y.append(np.any(x[i,:,:]))
```

Did I make a mistake somewhere here? 
Thanks!

Comment: It may seem that I'm picking at words, but you *can't* have a matrix with more (or less) than 2 dimensions. Your question is valid as a question about arrays (which can have arbitrary dimension.) I wrote a blog post about this: http://wilsonericn.wordpress.com/2011/09/15/the-first-thing-you-should-know-about-matrices/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a 10x5x5 matrix with `x[0,:,:] = 0` I would expect a result of:

```
[False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True]
```

because it is the first of **ten** 5x5 arrays which is all zero and not of **five**.

You get this result using

```
x.any(axis=1).any(axis=1)
```

or

```
x.any(axis=2).any(axis=1)
```

which means you first eliminate the second (axis=1) or the third (asix=2) dimension and then the remaining second (axis=1) and you get the only one dimension, which was originally the first one (axis=0).