# Replacing 2D subarray in 3D array if condition is met

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have a matrix that looks like this:

```
a = np.random.rand(3, 3, 3)

[[[0.04331462, 0.30333583, 0.37462236],
  [0.30225757, 0.35859228, 0.57845153],
  [0.49995805, 0.3539933,  0.11172398]],

 [[0.28983508, 0.31122743, 0.67818926],
  [0.42720309, 0.24416101, 0.5469823 ],
  [0.22894097, 0.76159389, 0.80416832]],

 [[0.25661154, 0.64389696, 0.37555374],
  [0.87871659, 0.27806621, 0.3486518 ],
  [0.26388296, 0.8993144,  0.7857116 ]]]
```

I want to check every block for a value smaller than 0.2. If value is smaller than 0.2 then the whole block equals 0.2. In this case:

```
[[[0.2 0.2 0.2]
  [0.2 0.2 0.2]
  [0.2 0.2 0.2]]

[[0.28983508 0.31122743 0.67818926]
 [0.42720309 0.24416101 0.5469823 ]
 [0.22894097 0.76159389 0.80416832]]

[[0.25661154 0.64389696 0.37555374]
 [0.87871659 0.27806621 0.3486518 ]
 [0.26388296 0.8993144  0.7857116 ]]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a vectorized way to get what you want.
Taking `a` from your example:

```
a[(a < 0.2).any(axis=1).any(axis=1)] = 0.2
print(a)
```

gives:

```
array([[[ 0.2       ,  0.2       ,  0.2       ],
        [ 0.2       ,  0.2       ,  0.2       ],
        [ 0.2       ,  0.2       ,  0.2       ]],

       [[ 0.28983508,  0.31122743,  0.67818926],
        [ 0.42720309,  0.24416101,  0.5469823 ],
        [ 0.22894097,  0.76159389,  0.80416832]],

       [[ 0.25661154,  0.64389696,  0.37555374],
        [ 0.87871659,  0.27806621,  0.3486518 ],
        [ 0.26388296,  0.8993144 ,  0.7857116 ]]])
```

---

**Explanation:**

Taking another example where each step will be more clear:

```
a = np.array([[[0.51442898, 0.90447442, 0.45082496],
               [0.59301203, 0.30025497, 0.43517362],
               [0.28300437, 0.64143037, 0.73974422]],
              [[0.228676  , 0.59093859, 0.14441217],
               [0.37169639, 0.57230533, 0.81976775],
               [0.95988687, 0.43372407, 0.77616701]],
              [[0.03098771, 0.80023031, 0.89061113],
               [0.86998351, 0.39619143, 0.16036088],       
               [0.24938437, 0.79131954, 0.38140462]]])
```

Let's see which elements are less than 0.2:

```
print(a < 0.2)
```

gives:

```
array([[[False, False, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, False, False]],

       [[False, False,  True],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, False, False]],

       [[ True, False, False],
        [False, False,  True],
        [False, False, False]]])
```

From here we would like to get indices of those 2D arrays that have at least one `True` element: `[False, True, True]`. We require [`np.any`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) for this. Note that I will be using [`np.ndarray.any`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.any.html) method chaining here instead of nesting function calls of `np.any`. <sup>1</sup>

Now just using `(a < 0.2).any()` will give just `True` because by default it performs logical OR over all dimensions. We have to specify `axis` parameter. In our case we will be fine with either `axis=1` or `axis=2`.<sup>2</sup>

```
print((a < 0.2).any(axis=1))
```

gives<sup>3</sup>:

```
array([[False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True],
       [ True, False,  True]])
```

From here we get desired boolean indices by applying another `.any()` along the rows:

```
print((a < 0.2).any(axis=1).any(axis=1))
```

gives:

```
array([False,  True,  True])
```

Fianlly, we can simply use this [boolean index array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) to replace the values of the original array:

```
a[(a < 0.2).any(axis=1).any(axis=1)] = 0.2
print(a)
```

gives:

```
array([[[0.51442898, 0.90447442, 0.45082496],
        [0.59301203, 0.30025497, 0.43517362],
        [0.28300437, 0.64143037, 0.73974422]],

       [[0.2       , 0.2       , 0.2       ],
        [0.2       , 0.2       , 0.2       ],
        [0.2       , 0.2       , 0.2       ]],

       [[0.2       , 0.2       , 0.2       ],
        [0.2       , 0.2       , 0.2       ],
        [0.2       , 0.2       , 0.2       ]]])
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Just compare chaining:

```
a[(a < 0.2).any(axis=1).any(axis=1)] = 0.2
```

with nesting:

```
a[np.any(np.any(a < 0.2, axis=1), axis=1)] = 0.2
```

I think the latter is more confusing.

<sup>2</sup>For me this was difficult to comprehend at first. What helped me was to draw an image of a 3x3x3 cube, print results for different axis, and check which axis correspond to which directions. Also, here is an explanation of using axis with `np.sum` in 3D case: [Axis in numpy multidimensional array.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24281263/axis-in-numpy-multidimensional-array)

<sup>3</sup>One could expect to get `[False,  True,  True]` at once which is not the case. For explanation see this: [Small clarification needed on numpy.any for matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684501/small-clarification-needed-on-numpy-any-for-matrices)

Answer (score -2):

Since you have three layer to your matrix, try this (having your matrix being a):

```
for x in a:
    for y in x:
        for z in y:
            if z < 0.2:
                z=0.2
```

Comment: The key to efficiency with numpy is performing vectorized operations for a whole array at once, not using nested loops. Also, this is not what OP is asking for.

Answer (score -2):

```
for i, block in enumerate(a):
    if (block < 0.2).flatten().any():
        a[i] = np.ones(np.shape(block)) * 0.2

print(a)

array([[[ 0.2       ,  0.2       ,  0.2       ],
        [ 0.2       ,  0.2       ,  0.2       ],
        [ 0.2       ,  0.2       ,  0.2       ]],

       [[ 0.28983508,  0.31122743,  0.67818926],
        [ 0.42720309,  0.24416101,  0.5469823 ],
        [ 0.22894097,  0.76159389,  0.80416832]],

       [[ 0.25661154,  0.64389696,  0.37555374],
        [ 0.87871659,  0.27806621,  0.3486518 ],
        [ 0.26388296,  0.8993144 ,  0.7857116 ]]])
```